# Is there a conjugate prior for normal location family N(x|u,1) such that the mean is always positive?

Tags: bayesian, conjugate-prior, constrained-regression

The conjugate prior to normal location family is usually a normal distribution. However, I want to constrain the mean to be positive.

Is there a conjugate prior to the normal location family $x\sim N(u,1)$ such that the mean $u>0$ is always positive?

Maybe a truncated normal distribution?
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/573694/bayesian-posterior-with-truncated-normal-prior

However, truncated normal is not that helpful because it is a strong prior in terms of the posterior mean is going to be difficult to approach the boundary, unlike lognormal and gamma.

Anything else? I tried gamma, inverse gamma, but I am not able to complete the square with the $\log u$ in the exponents of gamma.

Comment: Could you please provide me with a link? I said it was conjugate prior because I read https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/573694/bayesian-posterior-with-truncated-normal-prior . I did not go through the derivation though.

Comment: Certainly it's possible I made an error somewhere. (note however that you didn't say it was conjugate, you simply asked if it was; if you had a reason to believe it was the case, the right thing to do is give that reasoning or link to it in the question.)

Comment: You are right that I should have given URL. My question is really is there a flexible family like Inverse gamma, gamma, or chisquare that can be the conjugate prior for the mean? However, I may also have read somewhere else that Truncated Normal is not a conjugate prior for Normal likelihood. I have updated my question according to your suggestion.

Comment: I took another look at it now that I'm not in a hurry and realized that I screwed up the calculation that led my first comment; I've removed the original comment.

Comment: so is the truncation point of the prior and posterior the same?